# binding and unbinding mousedown handler upon mousedown and mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, mousemove, mousedown

I have an html table that has drag'n'drop columns, resizable rows, and resizable columns that change based on mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup. For better performance, should I have the document constantly checking if "mouse is down and if so, is it for drag'n'drop, resizable rows, or resizable columsn" during mousemove or should I attach the mousemove handlers to the document upon mousedown on a specific location and then dettach it upon mouseup? How costly is it to bind and unbind handlers upon clicking? Here is an example of the document always checking for mousedown vs only checking between mousedown and mouse clicks:

```
/* document is always checking mousemove */

$(selector).mousedown(function(){
    dropndrag = true;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(){
    if (dropndrag == true) {
        //do mouse move stuff
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    if (dropndrag == true) {
        dropndrag = false;
    }
});


/* mousemove only bound to document after mousedown */

$(selector).mousedown(function(){
    // attach handlers
    $(document).mousemove(mousemove); 
    $(document).mouseup(mouseup);
});

function mousemove(){
    // do mouse move stuff;
};

function mouseup() {
    //unbind mousemove and mouseup handlers
    $(document).off('mousemove', mousemove);
    $(document).off('mouseup', mouseup);
}
```

Comment: I always prefer checking the variables, seems faster!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely binding/unbinding is excess operations, which I'm sure slower than 1 variable in a "global" context where you store the status of it.
Also a good practice considered having 1 document listener for each event and filter, such as "switch/case" which only will fire functions for certain elements, for example:

```
var events = ['mousedown', 'mouseup', 'mousemove'];

var dragged = false; 

var eventHandler = function (e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'mousedown':

            switch (e.srcElement.id) {
                case 'test-block':
                    if (dragged) return;
                    dragged = true;

                    console.log('you clicked on the test-block');
                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 'mouseup':

            break;
        case 'mousemove':

            break;
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    $(document)[events[i]](eventHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fastest method might be event delegation: 
`document.addEventListener('onmousemove', myEventHandler);`

There's a good example and discussion of why this is fastest [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#Events).

Even better would be attaching the event listener to specific DOM objects, in your case a `<div>` or similar that wraps your table:
`document.getElementById("mydiv").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";` (Example from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp).)

This way, you avoid the overhead of repeatedly attaching and removing the handlers, and you also avoid your handlers being triggered by events that won't trigger any changes (ie moving the mouse around during mousedown somewhere else in the page).